# Correct API version for reference

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

How do I know what properties I can call from a reference object? It depends on the type of resource I'm referencing. The docs say to find out I can output the reference to that resource in deployment and see what it contains.

But the reference function takes an API version. How can I find out which API version is correct for the type of resource I want to reference?

Example in ARM script:

```
"outputs": {
    "fullReferenceOutput": {
    "type": "object",
    "value": "[reference(parameters('logicapp_Name'), '2016-12-01', 'Full')]"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example for such API call?

Comment: Done! Ive added how ive tried to get the right version in an arm script.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to [provide the API version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#parameters-3) **if** your template doesn't define the resource you're referencing.

You can use the `providers` [ARM function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#providers) to dynamically determine the latest valid API version.

So `providers('Microsoft.Web', 'sites').apiVersions[0]` will evaluate to the latest API.